# passing rowid inside editoptions dataUrl in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, editmode

Code

```js
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: 'LegalEntitiesAjax/GetMyData', 
    postData: function (rowid) {
        return {
            myVar: rowid
        }
    },
```

I need  to pass the rowid to `GetMyData` action, and unfortunately, `myVar` is null when hitting the action in the Controller.

Any hints on how to do this simple thing?

Comment: **You should include in every question the information about the version of jqGrid which you use and the fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The possibility to use `postData` was not in old (retro) versions of jqGrid. Some more old versions allows to define `postData` only inside of `ajaxSelectOptions` option. More late versions allows to use `postData` inside of `editoptions` and more later version allows to define `dataUrl` as function too.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use the latest version (4.13.3) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork which I develop. It has all above functionality. It's available for free under MIT/GPLv2 license and can be used from [CDNs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or be downloaded from GitHub, npm, bower, NuGet or from Maven Central. The package name is everywhere: "free-jqGrid".

Comment: Hi Oleg, we are using 4.4.4 version. What are my options then?

Comment: You should not use retro versions. The version 4.4.4 is too old (3.5 years old) and it's dead. I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.13.3. It's the version which I develop. It's mostly compatible with 4.4.4, but contains a lot of bug fixes, performance improvements and many new features describes in README to every published version and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) articles. Basis introduction can be found [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) too.

Comment: Hi Oleg, sadly I can't upgrade in the blink of an eye - that's not the scope of my task. though it would make sense, I am not the one that decides to upgrade.

Comment: I can't help you in the case. You posted some question, which shows that you *need* some features, which not exist in version 4.4.4. For example you can't productively use `dataUrl` in your scenario. Thus you have some alternatives: 1) don't use some buggy features and to reduce your requirements; 2) modify the code of 4.4.4 yourself to and to work with patched jqGrid 4.4.4; 3) upgrade to free jqGrid 4.13.3 or to Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.1 (purchasing licenses required). You should choose the best way for you/your company.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg, i will rewrite the edit to use a custom pop up. I much prefer it anyways since I have control over what is happening.